# SBT / Spring-AspectJ / compile-time weaving

Tags: spring, scala, maven, sbt, aspectj

I'm using scala 2.10, sbt 0.12.2 and Spring.

I would like to enable Spring-AspectJ compile-time weaving with SBT. I know that a great Maven plugin makes that work:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <complianceLevel>1.6</complianceLevel>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Does an efficient way to do the same thing exist at SBT side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am not an SBT or Scala user. But do you mean something like this?

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-aspectj

Comment: Yes, exactly, but it currently does not have the wanted feature. If you look at the "issues" part of this project, I've explained what I wish. :)  Author seems ok to try to achieve this requirement for the next sbt-aspectj version.

Comment: Fine. So at least now we have a link to your potential future solution here. ;-)

Comment: Yes :) Let's hope ;)  Thanks

Comment: @Mik378 Looking at the empty issue page I guess the issue is fixed